# Using a form to call a javascript and then put the calculated values into the form

Tags: javascript, html

I am enrolled in an online class and I keep reading the section of my book for js inclusion and I can't figure this out. Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong. Im trying to call the function to take in the weight and display the calculations back in the form text boxes. I cant find anything on the internet like this or explains how it works. Why can't this just be like C++ :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
    function Weight()
    {
    var mercury = earth*(.378);
    var venus = earth*(.907);
    var mars = earth*(.377);
    var jupiter = earth*(2.364);
    var saturn = earth*(.916);
    var uranus = earth*(.889);
    var neptune = earth*(1.125);
    var pluto = earth*(.067);
    var sun = earth*(27.072);
    var moon = earth*(.166);

    }
</script>

<body>

<form action="javascript:Weight(earth);">
  Enter Your Weight on Earth:<br>
  <input type="text" name="earth">
  <br><br>
  Mercury:<br>
  <input type="text" name="mercury">
  <br>
  Venus:<br>
  <input type="text" name="venus">
  <br>
  Mars:<br>
  <input type="text" name="mars">
  <br>
  Jupiter:<br>
  <input type="text" name="jupiter">
  <br>
  Saturn:<br>
  <input type="text" name="saturn">
  <br>
  Uranus:<br>
  <input type="text" name="uranus">
  <br>
  Neptune:<br>
  <input type="text" name="neptune">
  <br>
  Pluto:<br>
  <input type="text" name="pluto">
  <br>
  Sun:<br>
  <input type="text" name="sun">
  <br>
  Moon:<br>
  <input type="text" name="moon">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't magically get the values of the textboxes... and it doesn't magically set then either. I still fail to see why a form submit is being used in this case.

Comment: *"I cant find anything on the internet like this or explains how it works"*: you must be talking about a different internet then. It is literally [full of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+html+read+number+from+input).

Comment: Ok let me give it another try with those resources! Thanks for the articles! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

- Created an array `planetArray` containing the planets information
- Added an attribute `id` to the submit input
- Attached click event to `submitButton`. In the function get the earth input value and iterate over `planetArray` and calculate the weight value respectively on planets

```js
var planetsArray = [{name: "mercury",weight: 0.378}, {name: "venus",weight: 0.907}, {name: "mars",weight: 0.377}, {name: "jupiter",weight: 2.364}, {name: "saturn",weight: 0.916}, {name: "uranus",weight: 0.889}, {name: "neptune",weight: 1.125}, {name: "pluto",weight: 0.067}, {name: "sun",weight:27.072}, {name: "moon",weight: 0.166}],
    submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

// Attach click event
submitButton.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var earth = document.getElementsByName('earth')[0];
    planetsArray.forEach(function (p) {
      var elem = document.getElementsByName(p.name)[0],
          weight = p.weight * +earth.value;
      elem.value = weight.toFixed(2);
    });
};
```

```html
<form action="javascript:Weight(earth);">
  Enter Your Weight on Earth:<br>
  <input type="text" name="earth">
  <br><br>
  Mercury:<br>
  <input type="text" name="mercury">
  <br>
  Venus:<br>
  <input type="text" name="venus">
  <br>
  Mars:<br>
  <input type="text" name="mars">
  <br>
  Jupiter:<br>
  <input type="text" name="jupiter">
  <br>
  Saturn:<br>
  <input type="text" name="saturn">
  <br>
  Uranus:<br>
  <input type="text" name="uranus">
  <br>
  Neptune:<br>
  <input type="text" name="neptune">
  <br>
  Pluto:<br>
  <input type="text" name="pluto">
  <br>
  Sun:<br>
  <input type="text" name="sun">
  <br>
  Moon:<br>
  <input type="text" name="moon">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello javascript doesn't work in that way as you think.I can't teach you the whole thing here ,there are lot of information/articles in internet you may search them ,but  I can suggest you a solution of what you wanted to do .Check the below code hope it helps

```js
var earth=document.getElementById("earth");
var mercury=document.getElementById("mercury");
var venus=document.getElementById("venus");
var mars=document.getElementById("mars");

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
mercury.value=(earth.value) *(.378); 
venus.value=(earth.value) *(.907); 
mars.value=(earth.value) *(.377); 

 };
```

```html
<form name ="my">
  Enter Your Weight on Earth:<br>
  <input type="text" id="earth" name="earth">
  <br><br>
  Mercury:<br>
  <input type="text" id="mercury" name="mercury">
  <br>
  Venus:<br>
  <input type="text" id="venus" name="venus">
  <br>
  Mars:<br>
  <input type="text" id="mars" name="mars">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="button" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was on the right track! When i went back to edit the code from the articles I went and changed name to ID and put in the get elements by id  with the formulas. I think my biggest trouble was figuring out how to call the function from the form. I am so used to C++ this is so weird that they have all these rules form merging code.

Comment: This is so wierd. When i run that code in my editor it wont work but when i click on the snippet it does.

Comment: Do you have to use any special tags that are not visible for that script

Comment: no not at all pure javascript check this fiddle also  https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/n3xh6294/